# How can I call a function from a class in a WordPress plugin?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using a WordPress plugin called "Cartpauj PM" for private messages, and I want to show in the main page of my website the number of new messages.

The plugin has a file `pm-class.php`, where it has a class `cartpaujPM`, and inside there is a function that gets the new messages that goes like this:

```
function getNewMsgs()
    {
        global $wpdb, $user_ID;

        $get_pms = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT id FROM $this->tableMsgs WHERE (to_user='$user_ID' AND parent_id=0 AND to_del<>1 AND message_read=0 AND last_sender<>'$user_ID') OR (from_user='$user_ID' AND parent_id=0 AND from_del<>1 AND message_read=0 AND last_sender<>'$user_ID')"));
        return $wpdb->num_rows;
    }
```

How could I call this function in my theme template files? In the plugin files it calls like `$example_variable=this->getNewMsgs();` doing a `echo $example_variable` after.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$some_variable = new cartpaujPM();

$some_variable->getNewMsgs();
```

Comment: lol just like i tought, basic...... the downside of not knowing =) thank you sir!

Comment: @Chris_O some explaination as to what is being done would be helpful to myself and presumably a lot of others that are new to this. Thanks.